# Alternative for string.format while creating REST GET route

Tags: c#, rest, get, string.format

I add the following key to config file and I use `string.format` to create complete `GET` request.

```
 <add key="GetUserDetail" value="/search/user/searchterm={0}/rolename={1}/{2}/{3}">
```

Sometimes, the `GET` request has too many parameters and I mess up with string.format.

**Questions:**

- How to avoid `string.format` in this case?
- Am I correct in forming the `GET` request by adding a key to config and later manipulating it. Is there any other method generally followed?

Comment: Are you ending up with too many rollname arguments?  I'm assuming that searchterm is always a scalar value.

Comment: @woogy Not just too many role name but also the search criteria, searchterm, rolename, status, gelocation, etc

Answer (score 0):

I would try passing the rollname arguments as comma separated values, i.e.,

```
     yourserviceurl.com/search/user/searchterm=foo/rolename=admin,user,otherrole
```

Then you can split the string on the commas ( or whatever delimiter makes sense for your situation) to get each rollname.